# python arguments in verb noun formation

Tags: python

I'm use to using `argparse` to setup command line programs like

```
./app.py -a action -e something
```

I'm wondering if there is a good way to do the verb/noun type syntax like

```
./app get hosts
```

Also

```
./app get hosts -cloud=aws
```

Comment: I really like [`click`'s Groups](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: In case click's docs aren't clear enough, your verb would be a Command, and the noun would be an [Argument](http://click.pocoo.org/5/arguments/).

Comment: thanks that works great